# Sound file works fine in simulator but does not work in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have an app that plays sound  if a button is clicked.However, on a real device there is no sound. I checked all the solutions provided already by others in stackoverflow. Nothing seems to work. The app doesn't crash. It just doesn't play sound. In simulator it works perfectly. There is no problem with case sensitivity. Also, the phone is not mute.

Code:

```
var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!
```

When button is pressed:

```
let soundPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "bell-ringing-01", ofType: "mp3")
audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: soundPath!))
audioPlayer?.play()
```

There is also no errors while compiling and running. The app loads up well.

Comment: Filename case matters on a real device. Is the file *really* named `bell-ringing-01.mp3` and not something similar such as `bell-ringing-01.MP3` or `Bell-ringing-01.mp3` or any other variation?

Comment: The filename is "bell-ringing-01.mp3". I rechecked it just to be sure.

Comment: This is always one of two things:  Case sensitivity as @rmaddy says or the mute switch is on (or volume down).

Comment: Actually I checked it over and over again. No problem there with case sensitivity and mute switches. I don't know why the code runs in simulator fine but not on iPhone 7. Has it something to do with Swift 4 and new version of iOS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved! The following code works. After the *Play* button is pressed the bell sound is played**

func playSound(){

let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "bell-ringing-01", withExtension: "mp3")

```
    do{
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        try audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL!)

    }

    catch{

        print(error)
    }
   audioPlayer.play()
```

}

**The code that works only in simulator** but not in iPhone 7:

func playSound() {

```
   // let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: selectedSoundFileName, withExtension: "wav")

    let soundPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "bell-ringing-01", ofType: "mp3")

    audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: soundPath!))
    audioPlayer?.play()




}
```

> Without adding the *AVAudioSession* the code runs *only in* simulator but not in my iPhone 7.

Answer (score 0):

I guess adding these two lines solved the problem in the existing code:

> try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
>
> try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

Answer (score 0):

We were having the same problem in a Xamarin-based iOS app that uses Xam.Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer to play sounds from shared resource files (i.e. resource files that are defined in a cross-platform project so they can be used on both Android and iOS).

Xam.Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer played the resource .wav files on Android and on the iOS Simulator without any issues. However, no sound was produced on a real iOS device (an iPhone7) that we were using for testing.

Adapting Saad's [Swift solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52031361/15286360) to C# Xamarin calls fixed the issue. In our app's iOS-specific Xamarin project, we added the following one-time calls before attempting to play any resource-based sound files:

```
AVAudioSession.SharedInstance().SetCategory(AVAudioSession.CategoryPlayback);
AVAudioSession.SharedInstance().SetActive(true);
```